# How to update all parts of a web page containing the same object without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm using Javascript to make part of my web page editable for logged-in admin users. In one page, I have cards that display information about three people from the database. The cards contain username, skills, and bio fields. The username is also used a second time in the bio.

When the edit button is clicked, the first username, skills, and the bio without the username become editable. And when I change the username and click on the save button only the first username changes. For the one in the bio to update I need to reload the page even though they have the same id in my HTML template. How can I change the second one as well without reloading the page?

about.html:

```
% extends "potbs/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'potbs/about.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      {% for member in team_members %}
      <div class="col" id="border">

      <!--If user is admin, show edit button-->
        {% if user.is_superuser %}
        <div class="position-relative" id="edit_button_{{member.id}}" style="display: block;">
          <button class="btn btn-lg position-absolute top-0 end-0" id="edit_profile" data-id="{{member.id}}" data-username="{{member.username}}">
          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-solid" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;"></i></button>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 center-block text-center">
          <!--Display profile picture-->
            <img class="pp" id="pp_{{member.id}}" src="{{member.profile_picture.url}}" alt="{{member.username}}">

          <!--Edit form-->
            <div class="form-group" id="edit_{{member.id}}">
            </div>
     
          <!--Display username,skills and bio-->
            <div id="remove_{{member.id}}" style="display: block;">
              <h3 class="username" id="username_{{member.id}}">{{member.username}}</h3>
              <p class ="skills" id="skills_{{member.id}}">{{member.skills}}</p>
              <div class="bio">
                  <strong class="username" id="username_{{member.id}}"  style="font-size: large;">{{member.username}}, </strong><p id="bio_{{member.id}}">{{member.bio}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

about.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    const button = document.querySelectorAll("#edit_profile")
    button.forEach(function(button){
        button.onclick = function(){
            
            const memberID = button.dataset.id;
            const usernameID = button.dataset.username;
            const username = document.getElementById(`username_${memberID}`);
            const skills = document.getElementById(`skills_${memberID}`);
            const bio = document.getElementById(`bio_${memberID}`);

            //Create textareas for editable fields
            let edit_username = document.createElement("textarea");
            edit_username.setAttribute("rows", "1");
            edit_username.innerHTML = username.innerHTML
            edit_username.id = `edit_username_${memberID}`;
            edit_username.className = `form-control username ${usernameID}`;

            let edit_skills = document.createElement("textarea");
            edit_skills.setAttribute("rows", "1");
            edit_skills.innerHTML = skills.innerHTML;
            edit_skills.id = `edit_skills_${memberID}`;
            edit_skills.className = "form-control skills";

            let edit_bio = document.createElement("textarea");
            edit_bio.setAttribute("rows", "5");
            edit_bio.innerHTML = bio.innerHTML;
            edit_bio.id = `edit_bio_${memberID}`;
            edit_bio.className = "form-control bio";
            edit_bio.style.borderRadius = "15px";

            //Create cancel button
            const cancelButton = document.createElement("button");
            cancelButton.innerHTML = "Cancel";
            cancelButton.id = `cancelButton_${memberID}`;
            cancelButton.className = "btn btn-danger col-3";
            cancelButton.style.margin = "10px";

            //Create save button
            const saveButton = document.createElement("button");
            saveButton.innerHTML = "Save";
            saveButton.id = `saveButton_${memberID}`;
            saveButton.className = "btn btn-success col-3";
            saveButton.style.margin = "10px";

            //Hide the edit button and current content
            document.getElementById(`edit_button_${memberID}`).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(`remove_${memberID}`).style.display = "none";
        
            //Add textarea fields to the div
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(edit_username);
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(edit_skills);
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(edit_bio);
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(saveButton);
            document.getElementById(`edit_${memberID}`).append(cancelButton);

            // When the cancel button is clicked
            cancelButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
                cancel(memberID);
            })

            // When the save button is clicked
            saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                edit_username = document.getElementById(`edit_username_${memberID}`);
                edit_skills = document.getElementById(`edit_skills_${memberID}`);
                edit_bio = document.getElementById(`edit_bio_${memberID}`);

                
                fetch(`/edit_profile/${memberID}`,{
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username: edit_username.value,
                        skills: edit_skills.value,
                        bio: edit_bio.value,
                    })
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result[`error`]){
                    cancel(memberID)
                    } 
                    else {
                        username.innerHTML = result.username;
                        skills.innerHTML = result.skills;
                        bio.innerHTML = result.bio;
                        cancel(memberID) 
                        
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    console.log(edit_username.value);
                }) 
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: check what `result`, `username`, `skills` and `bio` variables are in fetch callback function. And make sure there are no errors in the console